# What is the opposite of javascript window.stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, browser, methods

Once I've executed `window.stop()`, how can I resume default actions?

I need to make toggle/switch function, that once fired will run `window.stop()`, and with second run will recover window actions disabled by `window.stop()`.

Comment: `stop` stops any current downloads. So what do you expect to happen when you "unstop"?

Comment: restart them again or refresh

Comment: `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Yes, but this reload all elements, and I want only to restart from moment when it stopped, is it possible?   I mean, leave elements that already loaded and restart only these which were stopped/paused.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: You could implement a limited form yourself by looping through all images on the page and toggling their URL if they haven't fully loaded, but that may not work in all browsers. I certainly don't know any inbuilt method. Remember that stopping and pausing are very different ideas.

Comment: window.stop() will stop all request currently executing unless the resource your are trying to restart knows how to resume i.e based on some form of session data,calling window.location.reload() will restart the request a fresh assuming the request has not been cached by the browser.To better answer your question you need to define what you mean by "recover".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misunderstood before how window.stop() works.

I was wrong, there are no any "direct inbuilt" javascript method to reload ONLY THESE ELEMENTS stopped by window.stop(), so by this meaning it's impossible.

However, if it's needed, we can:

- loop through each element on the site by our own function
- cut website in sections, and load them one by one with ajax, so we will have to reload only specific sections
  --but I think either one of these it's too complex to implement to be worthy

So, to "pause website for moment" window.stop() it's not good choice.